# d3 responsive multiple lines

Tags: d3.js, responsive-design

I used the code from this article to build an initial responsive line graph:

https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/

I updated it to allow drawing of multiple lines. I'm driving the lines with data in an angular directive and the code to draw the lines is more like this (this is coffeescript but you get the idea, the seriesConfig is a custom JS object that has info about the data):

```
for series in seriesConfig

    newLine = d3.svg.line()
      .x((d) -> return xScale(getXValue(d)))
      .y((d) -> return yScale(getYValue(d, series)))
```

The part I'm struggling with is updating the lines again when the browser is resized. In his article he uses this code where the line is stored as a variable:

```
graph.selectAll('.line').attr("d", line)
```

However here I have multiple lines. What is the appropriate way to have each line redraw itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I assigned a unique ID to each line and stored it in a hash keyed to the ID and line, then in onResize I selected just that line's ID and updated it with the value in the hash.

The other issue I ran into was that his code was hooking onResize to only one line. I updated

```
d3.select(window).on "resize"
```

to be

```
d3.select(window).on "resize.#{lineId}"
```

so that there were multiple listeners assigned to the resize event as I guess you can namespace scope (through suffixes) unique instances of the event as I've done here.